# Word meaning 'having to do with rivers'

Tags: single-word-requests, geography

I had originally thought that the word **riparian** meant having to do with rivers, but it appears that it actually means only having to do with river *banks*. Is there a word that more exactly means having to do with rivers. For example,

> The darters (family: Percidae) such as the blackside darter live a
>   riparian existence, relying on the environment of fast moving waters
>   to protect them from other fish.

Comment: FWIW, I have seen "riparian" used /a lot/ to refer precisely to rivers.

Comment: I was going to offer http://www.thefreedictionary.com/estuarine, but upon reading discover it refers to only a specific portion of the river.  I too vote for fluvial.

Answer (score 30):

Consider,

***fluvial***

> Of, relating to, or inhabiting a river or stream [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluvial)

***fluviatile***

> : pertaining or peculiar to rivers; found in or near rivers. [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fluviatile)

Comment: _'Fluviatile'_ is worth more than the  +1 that I can give you. A gorgeous word.

Comment: @JohnMack You're welcome, John!

Answer (score 14):

*'Fluvial'* or *'riverine'*.

> fluvial fluvial
>   (ˈfluːvɪəl)
>   [a. F. fluvial, ad. L. fluviāl-is, f. fluvius river.]
>   Of or pertaining to a river or rivers; found or living in a river.
>   *1398 Trevisa Barth. De P.R. xix. lxv. (1495) 901 Yf fluuyall stones ben hette fyry hote and thenne quenchyd therin. 1599 A. M. tr. Gabelhouer's Bk. Physicke 33/2, Iij pintes of fluvial water. 1775 Romans Florida 316 This fluvial expedition. 1867 J. B. Rose tr. Virgil's æneid 190 The fluvial nymphs. 1875 Wond. Phys. World I. i. 39 The descent of fluvial ice frequently causes great disasters.*
>
> riverine riverine, a. and n.
>   (ˈrɪvəraɪn)
>   [f. river n.1]
>   A. adj.
>   1. Situated or dwelling on the banks of a river; riparian.
>   *1860 Chamb. Jrnl. XIV. 40 Swampville was in reality a riverine town. 1888 Inglis Tent Life 22 Such villages are common enough in these..riverine plains, all over India. 1898 G. W. Steevens With Kitchener to Khartum 78 Like all riverine peoples he is more clean than bashful.*
>   2. Of or pertaining to a river; resembling a river.
>   *1871 Graphic 29 April 382 The view at high water on the riverine curve is hardly surpassed in any European city. 1876 S. Birch Rede Lect. 24 The riverine navies of Egypt floated to the scene of action. 1884 E. Jenkins Week of Passion II. iv. 156 His face,..deeply rutted, here and there, with expressive valleys and riverine lines of wrinkle. 1898 Pall Mall Mag. May 9 Great riverine improvements..effected at great cost.*
>   B. n. The banks or vicinity of a river.
>   *1895 F. A. Swettenham Malay Sk. 215 All the dwellers on the riverine.*

Both from the Oxford English Dictionary.  Not that *'riverine'* clings to the perspective of a river 'from the bank', although it allows a  broader interpretation.

Rivers debouching into the Ocean are also referred at that point (where they are affected by tides and salt water) as *'estuarine'*.  It is curious though, that there is no well known word particularly associated with fast flowing freshwater.  EL&U member 'Eric' has, however, brought to our attention *'lotic'* (pertaining to fast moving water), and *'lentic'* (pertaining to still water).

Animals that live on, and in, streams and rivers are usually simply referred to as *'freshwater ...'*.

Comment: According to the OED *riverine* and *riverain* mean the same thing as *riparian* i.e. related to river banks. But *fluvial* is definitely the word the OP needs.

Comment: @WS2, respectfully disagree given the above quote is from the OED (see 2. Of or pertaining to a river).  Fluvial is better, but actually I'd go for _'lotic'_, from EL&U member Eric.

Comment: + 1 for "riverine": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Navy_Riverine_Squadron

Answer (score 8):

Does the word "***lotic***" work for you? It's not a commonly used word, granted, but it does appear to meet the needs of the OP.

> of, relating to, or living in actively moving water  — compare lentic.
> [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lotic)

Answer (score 6):

In a practical sense however, if the writer uses "lotic", how many of their readers will know its meaning?

If clarity is a requirement, then they could consider:

*The darters (family: Percidae) – such as the blackside darter – live in fast-flowing rivers and streams, relying on the environment of moving water to protect them from other fish.*

Comment: I concur @Cargill that "fast-flowing water" works for the majority of darters, and applies the KISS principle nicely. However, if the OP needs to generalize accurately about the habitat of the taxonomic group as a whole (not sure about the requirement for biological correctness here), then this term would not cover the darters that inhabit slow-moving streams, pools, and swamps. As exemplified by a number of the more practical responses posted herein, the most effective word will likely depend on the context, i.e., the specificity required for this application, and the intended audience.

Answer (score 5):

Why not start with the ancient Greek word for river [something  like 'potamos']

And the Latin word [something like 'flumen'].

Most words adopted into English are picked because they sound nice (or 'flow'!) even if they jumble sources (as in 'hehexadecimal') of various inflexions.

I'd vote for fluvial, but for fun you could try potamic.

Comment: This question is a request for real words; not to make one up.

Comment: Well-aimed: the word 'potamic' ("Of or relating to rivers; riverine", OED) is in current use, with a history going back to 1883. I'm just sad you swiped my word, even if you thought you made it up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the word you are looking for is **rivery**.

James Joyce: "In the river, all. . . [rivery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbF5hDU_F-U) was it.

Comment: *rivery* means either "like a river" (making the use in that pastiche of Joyce humorously tautologous), or "having lots of rivers" ("From rolling valley and rivery glen" in Yeats' "Wanderings of Oisin"). It wouldn't be used for "of a river".

Comment: "The Heron is a rivery sort of a bird. . ."